# Can't access to shared drive in workgroup

Tags: c, winapi, networking, workgroup

I have a workgroup with two machines (Two Windows Server 2012). I wanted to write a program that let me to create files/directories and ... on the remote machine. My workgroup setup:

Machine 1:

- Username: W1
- Name: WONE
- password: lalalala
- Workgroup: WLAB

Machine 2:

- Username: W2
- Name: WTWO
- password: lalalala
- Workgroup: WLAB

I have written the following program that works correctly on the local file system but when I wanted to create a file on the remote machine (i.e \WONE\Users\W1\Desktop\Sample.txt) from WTWO machine, it doesn't work. I run my program with administrator privilege too but nothing changed. My program:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>


bool MakeFileOnSystemAbsloute(const wchar_t* arg_path)
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa_FileSecurityAttribute;
    wchar_t c_FilePath[MAX_PATH];


    sa_FileSecurityAttribute.nLength = sizeof(sa_FileSecurityAttribute);
    sa_FileSecurityAttribute.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    sa_FileSecurityAttribute.bInheritHandle = FALSE;

    wcscpy_s(c_FilePath, MAX_PATH, arg_path);


    HANDLE h_CreatedFile = CreateFileW(c_FilePath, 0, 0, &sa_FileSecurityAttribute, CREATE_NEW, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if (h_CreatedFile)
    {
        CloseHandle(h_CreatedFile);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    return false;
}



int main()
{
    MakeFileOnSystemAbsloute(L"\\WONE\\Users\\W1\\Desktop\\Milad.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

Where is the problem? How should I fix this issue? Also, I read the following text from the internet, it seems I can't get access to the remote machine with my current account in local machine.

**Quote:**

> The fact that the machine with the shared drive is not on a domain is
> where your main problem is. In order to get this to work you will have
> to configure the Windows Service to run as a specific user, and then
> you'll have to create an identical user on the remote system with the
> same password. It might work then.
>
> The problem stems from the fact that in order to log in to a machine
> not in a domain, you have to log into that machine using an account
> that exists on that machine. The machine account for something else
> definitely won't exist on that local machine. By creating an identical
> user with an identical password, you might be able get the login to
> work."
>
> -sysadmin1138

Comment: The pathname to the server needs to start with two backslashes. `L"\\WONE"` starts with one backslash.

Comment: Also check what `GetLastError` returns if `h_CreatedFile` fails.

Comment: @Jabberwocky It gives 1326 as error. It means "The user name or password is incorrect."

Comment: You need first call [NetUseAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/gg651155(v=ws.11)) to set user name /password for remote system.

Comment: Then use `LogonUser()` to log in to the desired user account and get a token for it, then pass that token to `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()` to impersonate that user, then call `CreateFile()`. My test is successful. If you need the code sample, please let me know.